# Inner div height won't expand fill absolutely positioned outer div in IE7 Standards Compliance mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

**What's going on here, and how can it be fixed?**

The below markup creates a gray div that expands to fit the window but falls 100 pixels short on the top and right edges.  And then it creates an inner pink div that should fill the entire gray div.

The meta tag forces my IE8 browser to render in IE7 Standards Compliance mode -- and it also ***breaks*** the layout.  The pink div doesn't fill to expand the full height of it's parent.  It shows up as only about 20 pixels tall.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #canvas {
                background-color: #eee;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                right: 100px;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            .fill {
                background-color: pink;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything looks fine in modern browsers (tested Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: Adding `position: absolute;` to the inner div sorted it out, but I'm not sure what the reason is.  I'd appreciate an explanation if anyone has one to offer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**try resetting your "CSS":**

```
/* RESET YOUR CSS CODE */
*{ margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;height:auto;... bla bla bla ....}
```

**in you HTML doc:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* RESET CSS */
            *{ margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;height:auto; }

            /* YOUR CODE */
            #canvas {
                background-color: #eee;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                right: 100px;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            .fill {
                background-color: pink;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't fix the problem.